# Pacman is not found in msys2

Tags: git-bash

I just installed Git for Windows 2.22.0 which should include pacman, but I get an

```
bash: pacman: command not found
```

and I don't see the pacman executable in /usr/bin.

Comment: Tried installing it in Ubuntu and it only installed git, git-man and liberror-perl

Comment: Git doesn't include pacman. Why should it?

Comment: I'm referring to Git for Windows, not Git. Git for Windows comes bundled with Git Bash, and the latest update says it includes pacman. But! I think pacman is actually in the Git for Windows SDK